# Exchanging harddisk of Medion Akoya MD-98634 laptop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, raid

I am trying to replace the original 1TB harddisk of my Medion Akoya (MD-98634) with a Crucial BX100 SSD (250GB).

This is what I found out so far:
The original setup is running the 1TB HDD in a RAID of unknown kind, together with a built in 32GB Samsung SSD-chip (looks almost like the internal Wi-Fi adapter, but without antenna). These 32GB are used for storing the windows swap file.
When I replace the HDD with the SSD, Windows setup/recovery (flash-drive) wont find the drive, although it shows in the UEFI, just like the 32GB-chip.

This is what I want to achieve:
I want to either (if possible) run the Crucial in the RAID like the original Setup with swap file on the Samsung chip (would probably save me some trouble with the SSD in the future, if i don't deaktivate swap-file completely), or remove the 32GB Chip and have everything on the Crucial-SSD.

This is what I tried so far:
removing the 32GB-Chip - when I turn the laptop on it opens BIOS and wont even let me chose USB as Boot device. the only option is PXE Boot, which is disabled

changing SATA-Configuration from RAID to AHCI and then to IDE, with and without 32GB chip - still same problem

Updated BIOS - same problem

I downloaded the chipset driver from medion-hp, but I cannot find any way to implement it

mailing Medion - they told me to use the Hotline

calling Medion Support Pay-Hotline for several days - always getting info that no support members are available atm

BIOS version: 507

VBIOS version: Intel(R) GOP Driver [3.0.10.1010]

EC version: 5300057F20

ME FW version: 8.1.0.1248

please let me know if you need any other Info (like BIOS-Screenshots)

thank you for your time :)

regards

Akil

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if we knew what RAID configuration it was.  Its very likely the current boot configuration is in RAID mode thus the reason Windows Setup does not see it ( although you make no mention of which version of Windows )

Comment: My bad, it's Windows 8. No idea how to find ou what RAID, because in BIOS it doesnt say anything about it. In the meantime I deactivated fast boot, activated "Launch CSM" and deactivated secure Boot. Now it actually tries to boot from the empty SSD. But i cannot select USB/DVD as boot device :(

Comment: Are there any options to switch from something other than a RAID configuration.  Your not going to be able "remove" your SSD cache since its soldered to your motherboard.

Comment: with AHCI Mode instead of RAID mode, secure boot off and CSM on it tries to boot from SSD, but I cant find a way to boot from USB, although all USB-options are enabled. The cache is not solderes to the motherboard, its a removable device, just like the wi-fi adapter. at least i think that thats the cache because thats what i found with google when i was checking serial number or /w.e. on it

Comment: Alright; Enable `AHCI Mode` but disable CSM.

Comment: I enabled AHCI but when I disable CSM or secure boot, it starts right into BIOS again. With both enabled it tries to boot from SSD. I gave up on reinstalling Windows from flash drive and finally managed to boot from DVD. I will install clean Windows 8 now and try to activate it with the key I extracted from BIOS earlier .. will see if that works. I'll report back!

Comment: success! Windows up and running on the ssd now. Also I reformatted the cache and put the swapfile on it .. perfect! :D Thank you for everything, Ramhound :)